# Coremltools 5.1 on windows 10 gives "Unable to load libmodelpackage"

Tags: windows-10, coremltools

When I installed coremltools 5.1 on windows 10 (version 21H1, build 19043.1348, python 3.7.8) and opened a coreml model, I got the error message "*Unable to load libmodelpackage. Cannot make save spec*". The mlmodel can be found in this page https://github.com/likedan/Awesome-CoreML-Models

```
import coremltools
spec = coremltools.utils.load_spec(r"MNIST.mlmodel")
```

It works well in coremltools 4.1. Do you have any idea about this issue? coremltools 5.x does not support windows anymore? I did not find any information about windows support on the release note of coremltools.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Coremltools never supported windows and version 5.1+ -> https://github.com/apple/coremltools/issues/1348